# How to stop google cloud artifacts from affecting my firebase storage usage?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage, google-cloud-run, google-container-registry

I am using firebase storage for storing some files (maximum 30mb). My backend and frontend servers are deployed on Google Cloud Run.

Since last night, I am seeing this usage constantly after every 5min. Even without using the website my firebase storage has reached 1gb bytes stored.

[image]

I read that images stored in container registry use storage internally which causes the usage spike but I only have 1 image there, that too was deployed yesterday.

Why is it showing such a high usage after every 5min even if the website is not being used?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by google cloud run, because google cloud run access the website every 5 minutes. To keep it ready for incoming visitors. And you can learn more [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/3-ways-optimize-cloud-run-response-times).

To solve it you can follow these steps according to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout):

1. Go to Google Cloud Run.
2. Click on the service, then click Edit and deploy new revision.
3. Click on the container tab then edit the request time out

But keep in mind that there are quota limits which you can learn more about [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas#cloud_run_limits). But I suggest making something like a verification system in your website since hackers can keep fetching your website and increasing the usage.
I hope this helped

Comment: I didn't know this. Can you add any article where this is mentioned? And why does it hit the website every 5minutes?

Comment: I tried increasing the timeout but the pattern is still the same.

Comment: I have added the resource @SuryaMahla I don't know why the pattern is still the same but my guess is that you have a slow connection and google is still processing the increase or by default it was 15 minutes